# Auto connect to the wired net?

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I've installed Arch linux, and planned to used it remote and putty my way in.

But it does not seem to start up the interface at boot. I also want a static ip. Is there a config file like /etc/network/interfaces like on debian i can config, reboot and everything is ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Arch Linux Wiki article about [Configuring Network](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_Network).  The section [Static IP Address](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_Network#Static_IP_address) is probably most relevant.  Looks like the file `/etc/rc.conf` needs some values, and you'll have to configure DNS by editing `/etc/resolv.conf`.